# How to get realistic coloring on quick smoke/fire in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, color, photorealism

I'm relatively new to blender simulations and have been working with quick smoke and fire. Try as I might I can not get the color of the fire right, and have found no videos/tutorials explaining this. This is not a problem with how to use blender, I am just asking if anyone knows the best way to color realistic fire in Cycles render.

Comment: What does it mean *"get the color of the fire right"* for you? What is wrong with tutorials already on [Youtube on topic](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+realistic+fire+simulation)? What did you try and what didn't work for you? With answers to these questions others will have better idea in what aspect you need help

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102490/1853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the node setup I used for this scene. You don't have to copy the exact colors I used mess with it to get the right color.

Also I recommend Blender Guru's camp fire tutorial.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fires turn white due to overexposure of their medium, not the colour itself.

Comment: Thank you, that video helped a lot, I can't believe I haven't found it before!