# Fire simulation not working in eevee 2.81

Tags: physics, baking, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a fire simulation for an animation I'm making, but when I bake the simulation I get a strange result.

[image: Broken_Simulation]

It works completely fine in cycles,but I want to use eevee because it's a lot faster to render.

[image: Cycles_working]

There is no volumetric checkbox in blender 2.81, so I can't use that to fix my problems. I've been playing around with the settings of the simulation, but it ends the same. If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Here is my node setup (just in case).

[image: Node_network]

Here is my Smoke Domain Settings

[image: Smoke_Domain]

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug with respect to the Adaptive Domain settings – have you tried disabling Adaptive Domain (assuming you have it enabled)?

Comment: I disabled Adaptive Domain, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please post pictures of the Physics settings for the smoke domain, and the emitter.

Comment: Also, with the pricipled shader you don't need a separate node for the flames https://i.stack.imgur.com/Draxh.png see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102139/how-to-create-fire-materials-using-the-new-principled-volume-node-that-visually/102490#102490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was running into was that I needed to use a heat attribute node. Once I added that with the flame attribute, it worked. (I also didn't separate the nodes anymore)

[image: Node_Setup]

[image: Working_Fire]

Thank you everyone who helped.