# Issues in fire simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I'm using blender 2.81a on ubuntu 18.04.3 I'm try to setup a scene to make a house on fire soo I tried it very basic approach it didn't work, then I just wanted to test if the fire simulation is working stable in this version, I took a cube and used quick effects-smoke even in shading I deleted principled bsdf and added a principled volume and added an emission shader connected the both with add shader and plugged output into volume of output.
For flame color I added input-attribute gave it a name 'flames' and added color ramp set interpolation  to linear gave input from attribute-factor to color ramp factor then plugged the color output to a math node and changed it to multiply input is plugged to above node and below I gave a value of 30 and gave it's output to emission color but nothing changed (note: I didn't check the clamp option in multiply). I don't know whether it's a correct way to do fire simulations, if there is any other way to do it can anyone help with this.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102139/how-to-create-fire-materials-using-the-new-principled-volume-node-that-visually